# Flutter TapGestureRecognizer#5334d Navigation Error

Tags: android, flutter, dart

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            // getValueOfField();
            Navigator.push(
                context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => shop1()));
          },
          child: Icon(
            Icons.arrow_right_alt,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
          backgroundColor: Color(0xfff7892b),
        )
```

I just use this Navigation to my flutter App to Navigate on other page
but it was not working and giving an error in terminal

```
Handler: "onTap"
Recognizer:
  TapGestureRecognizer#5334d
```

Comment: Please post your full code

Answer (score 0):

Use this line of code instance in your code.

```
Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const shop1()));
```